# Link to function with IdaPython

Tags: ida, idapython

In my IdaPython script I print function that I found.

`print(func_address)`

How can I do that if user click  on this function (in output windows) Ida will jump to this function?

Answer (score 1):

Just print address as hex-value:

```
print("%08x" % func_address)
```

So in Output window:

```
Python>print(0x1001CC80)
268553344     # <---- this is not clickable
Python>print("%08x" % 0x1001CC80)
1001cc80      # <---- this is clickable
```

Comment: Is there any way to give a name to clickable? like "press here" and this link to address?

Comment: IDA can jump only if it knows the name or address. You can print a comment with address like `print("click on address to jump: %08x" % ea)`